# Why and how C++ changes values of old iterators

Tags: c++

I declared a pointer to vector::iterator and after that compared vector::begin() and vector::end() but by doing that it changed state in vector::iterator pointer that I previously declared. I tried copying iterator first and using that but it did not work either (first example). By declaring temporary copy outside of brackets this problem is being fixed (second example) but then I have one extra variable that I don't need. So what happens inside that iterator which changes state, and why it only happens in first one?

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> x{ 1, 2 };

    std::vector<int>::iterator *a = nullptr;

    {
        std::vector<int>::iterator b = x.begin();
        a = &b;
    }

    std::cout << &(**a) << '\n';

    x.begin() == x.end();

    std::cout << &(**a) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> x{ 1, 2 };

    std::vector<int>::iterator *a = nullptr;

    std::vector<int>::iterator b;
    {
        b = x.begin();
        a = &b;
    }

    std::cout << &(**a) << '\n';

    x.begin() == x.end();

    std::cout << &(**a) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Iterators have nothing to do with this. You're capturing the address of an automatic variable that is destroyed upon scope exit, leaving the captured address as a *dangling* pointer.

Comment: why would you do that? you almost never explicitly need a pointer when dealing with an iterator.

Comment: Iterators are cheap to copy. No need for pointers.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I used pointer because I needed a way to set it empty (nullptr), not making it pointer and using end() as empty did not work because after I edited vector, previous end() did not match end() of edited vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with iterators. You're creating a pointer to a local variable. When execution leaves the block the local variable was defined in, the local variable gets destroyed and your pointer becomes invalid:

```
int *a;
{
    int b;
    a = &b;
} // b is destroyed here
// a is now a garbage pointer
```

Your second example avoids the problem by defining the local variable in a bigger block so it stays alive longer.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case pointer `a` points to a local variable `b` that went out of scope, that is it is a dangling pointer and dereferencing it causes Undefined behavior.